# Inconsistent URL-decoding of HttpRequest.Path in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, urlencode

`HttpContext.Request.Path` seems to decode percent-encoded URLs sometimes, but not all the time and I'm struggling to understand its behaviour. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.path?view=aspnetcore-5.0) says nothing about encoding. I expect it to never decode the path, but testing on ASP.NET Core 3.1 I get results like this:

| Request URL | context.Request.Path | Percent decoded? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `http://localhost:5000/test%24` | `/test$` | Yes |
| `http://localhost:5000/test%24aa` | `/test$aa` | Yes |
| `http://localhost:5000/test%25a` | `/test%25a` | No |
| `http://localhost:5000/test%25aa` | `/test%aa` | Yes |
| `http://localhost:5000/test%20aa` | `/test%20aa` | No |

Is this a bug or is there some reason behind it?

Generated by creating an empty ASP.NET Core project in VS 2019 and changing the Startup class to

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request path = " + context.Request.Path);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request path = " + context.Request.Path);
            });
        }
    }
```

Program class unchanged from the template:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
```

**Edit:** answer from an ASP.NET contributor: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30655

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue (with "%2B" corresponding to literal value "+") and I finally understood what happened.

1. Note that `context.Request.Path` is of type `PathString` and has a `Value` property.
2. The default `Path.ToString()` overload doesn't return the same value as  `Path.Value` property:

   - `Path.Value` returns **a **partially* (see remark below)** decoded URL which seems reliable** (it is the real underlying/wrapped value).
   - `Path.ToString()` returns an encoded URL using the `Path.Value` property.
3. Also note that `PathString` can be converted to `string` and used as is in a method with a `string` parameter, so becareful using the `Value` property when necessary!

#### To summarize

- To have the decoded URL, use:

```cs
var decodedURL = context.Request.Path.Value;
```

**Remark***: note that «decoded» means all characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits will be converted to the corresponding char, but the special char '+' will not. If you want the '+' char to be also converted, consider using the following:

```cs
var decodedURL = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Path.Value); //Including '+' char to space
```

- To have the encoded URL, use:

```cs
var encodedURL = context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent();
```

#### Attention!

But beware, there is still an inconsistent use case due to **remark*** above.

Let's consider the example below:

| Real resource path | Encoded URL | context.Request.Path.Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /my+path example | /my%2Bpath+example | /my+path+example |

As you can notice, if you encode URLs with '+' char for spaces and "%2B" for literal char '+' (which is legal), then it is impossible to rebuild the real resource path from the `Path.Value`...

To avoid this, I would recommend to encode spaces as "%20", but becareful once again: don't use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` neither `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` (which will convert spaces to '+'), but **`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`**.

*As a small personal conclusion, there might be some good reasons (unknown to me) for the `Path.Value` property to be partially decoded, but in this case, the framework should provide another property to get the real raw/untouched URL*.

Hope this will help!

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you, that's a good write-up! I also got some answers here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30655 (forgot to post that here, but edited into the question now)

Comment: Thank you also for posting link to issue :)